# In git, list all tags since some tag

Tags: git, git-tag, git-rev-list

I'm using tags to identify release versions and to identify "development complete" commits for tasks.  Doing a `git tag` I get a list like the following.

```
> git tag
v0.1.0
task_1768
task_2011
task_1790
task_1341
v0.1.1
task_2043
task_2311
v0.1.2
```

Assuming that all tags point to commits on `master` branch, is there a way to list all tags since some tag?  For example, to generate a list of all tasks included in the `v0.1.2` release -- I'm looking for something like the following (which is not an actual command).

```
> git tag -l "task_*" --since v0.1.1
```

To get output like the following.

```
task_2043
task_2311
```

Is there a way to do this with `git tag`?

Is there a way to do this with `git rev-list`?

(Or some other git command?)

#### UPDATE

Based on the answers and comments the following is what I'm currently using.

```
> git log v0.1.1.. --decorate | grep -Eow 'tag: ([a-zA-Z0-9.-_]*)' | awk '{ print substr($0, 6); }'
task_2043
task_2311
v0.1.2

> git log v0.1.1.. --decorate | grep -Eow 'tag: ([a-zA-Z0-9.-_]*)' | awk '{ print substr($0, 6); }' | grep -Eo 'task_.*'
task_2043
task_2311
```

#### SECOND UPDATE

New selected answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for initially.  Much more elegant.

```
> git tag --contains v0.1.1
v0.1.1
task_2043
task_2311
v0.1.2

> git tag --contains v0.1.1 | grep -Eo 'task_.*'
task_2043
task_2311
```

Comment: When you say "since" do you mean "all tags that point to commits not reachable from master" or do you mean "all tags that point to commits with a commit/authorship date newer than the one pointed to by master?" The two are different and will yield different results.

Comment: Good question.  I mean "all tags that point to commits with a commit/authorship date newer than the one pointed to by v0.1.1."

Comment: I'm on my way out so I can't draft a solution at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that there is no one Git command that will do this.  You will likely need to write a short shell script that iterates through the output of `git tag`, fetches the commit (or authorship) timestamp from each one as well as from `HEAD` and compares the two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git tag --contains v0.1.1` will show you all tags that contain the given tag -- i.e. tags from which you can trace back in history and reach the given tag.

Answer (score 4):

you can provide a range for `git log`:

```
git log v1.1.0..
```

now you add the `--decorate` option which will list tags. There are other options you can add to log to limit the list to just the interesting ones or grep it for "tag":

```
git log v1.1.0.. --decorate | grep 'tag:'
```

Comment: +1 Nice and clean; something like `git log v0.1.1.. --decorate | awk '/tag:/{sub(/)$/, "", $4); print $4}'` is probably very close to the desired output.

Comment: Here's what works for my purposes: `git log v0.1.1.. --decorate | grep -Eow 'tag: (task_[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]*)' | grep -Eo 'task.*'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rev-list` to give you all revisions reachable by following the links from `master`, excluding any that can also be reached from `v0.1.1`:

```
git rev-list --tags master --not v0.1.1
```

You can then run that through `git describe`:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags `git rev-list --tags master --not v0.1.1`
```

This may give you duplicate copies of the tags (and will likely include `v0.1.1` itself), but it should be a start to getting the list you require.